# Is there eslint plugin for creating margins between variables?

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have one more variables which I want to seperate with a line. And I am looking for a plugin for my ESlint.
For example:

```
// my code:
 const {label, size, placeholder, className, value, onChange, disabled, required, readonly, type, ...nextProps} = props;
 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState<string>('');
 const handleChange = (event:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(event);
    }
    setInputValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
```

```
// desirable code:
 const {label, size, placeholder, className, value, onChange, disabled, required, readonly, type, ...nextProps} = props;

 const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState<string>('');

 const handleChange = (event:React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (onChange) {
      onChange(event);
    }
    setInputValue(event.currentTarget.value);
  };
```

By the way, if there is such seperation like in my desirable result above, ESlint says it is an error. Are there ways to fix it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting from ESLint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably need prettier to do the formatting for you. `npm i -d prettier`, and then if you are using VS Code you have to install the Prettier extension too. Lastly, just Ctrl + Shift + P on VS Code and then type Format Document, then choose `prettier` as your default formatter.

`package.json`

```
   "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^8.15.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
        "prettier": "^2.6.2"
     }
```

For additional convenience, go to File > Preferences > Settings, search Format on Save, and enable it - your code will be auto-formatted everytime you save.